# Problem connection to a standby database during the create proccess

Tags: oracle, listener, standby

I'm trying to install an Oracle Standby Database 19c. I have a Rac Database 19c and now I'm with the firsts steps to create de standby.

I have in nomount state the standby database

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile='/u02/app/oracle/product/19c/db_1/dbs/initSECDB19.ora';
ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 4294963272 bytes
Fixed Size          8904776 bytes
Variable Size         788529152 bytes
Database Buffers     3489660928 bytes
Redo Buffers            7868416 bytes
```

and now I'm trying to connect to the standby with sys user but I get the ORA-12514 error.

```
[oracle@prima191 ~]$ sqlplus sys/manager@pridb19 as sysdba                                
...
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0
SQL> exit

Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0
[oracle@prima191 ~]$ sqlplus sys/manager@SECDB19 as sysdba
...
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

This is the listener parameters at database level

```
Primary:

SQL> show parameter listener

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
forward_listener             string
listener_networks            string
local_listener               string   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.111)(PORT=1521))
remote_listener              string   prima19-cluster-scan:1521
listener_networks            string
SQL> exit


STANDBY:

SQL> show parameter listener

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
forward_listener             string
listener_networks            string
local_listener               string
remote_listener              string  secun19-cluster-scan:1521
listener_networks            string
```

tnsnames.ora (PRIMARY )

```
PRIDB19 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = prima19-cluster-scan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pridb19.vboxlab.es)
    )
  )

SECDB19 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = secun19-cluster-scan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = secdb19.vboxlab.es)(UR=A)
    )
  )
```

LISTENER.ORA (STANDBY)

```
[grid@secun191 admin]$ cat listener.ora
LISTENER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER))))        # line added by Agent
LISTENER_SCAN3=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN3))))        # line added by Agent
LISTENER_SCAN2=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN2))))        # line added by Agent
LISTENER_SCAN1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN1))))        # line added by Agent
ASMNET1LSNR_ASM=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=ASMNET1LSNR_ASM))))      # line added by Agent
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_ASMNET1LSNR_ASM=ON       # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_ASMNET1LSNR_ASM=SUBNET     # line added by Agent
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER_SCAN1=ON        # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER_SCAN1=OFF     # line added by Agent - Disabled by Agent because REMOTE_REGISTRATION_ADDRESS is set
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER_SCAN2=ON        # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER_SCAN2=OFF     # line added by Agent - Disabled by Agent because REMOTE_REGISTRATION_ADDRESS is set
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER_SCAN3=ON        # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER_SCAN3=OFF     # line added by Agent - Disabled by Agent because REMOTE_REGISTRATION_ADDRESS is set
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER=ON      # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER=SUBNET        # line added by Agent

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = secdb19)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/grid/product/19c/grid_1)
      (SID_NAME = secdb19)
    )
  )
```

I don't know what's the problem for ORA-12514 error.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the output of 'lsnrctl status' on the standby server (which I'm guessing from what you've shown is a vbox vm on your workstation).  And your listener is not set to listen for IP connections, just IPC.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the service used in tnsnames.

Comment: since you show no other evidence, we'll have to take your word for it.  You should update your answer to show that evidence.  That would be the output of 'lsnrctl status' and the corrected tnsnames.ora.